# Does madhi and mani during urination after masturbation invalidate fast?

Tags: practical-islam, sawm, ghusl

I am a Muslim. I masturbated but didn’t let mani come out. Then after I stopped, it came out during urine. I am not sure whether that was mani, wadi or madhi. Does this invalidate my expiatory fast?

Answer (score -2):

Madhi doesnt't , mani does.
madhi is max a coin size, more then that is mani.

Comment: From any other person's perspective, this reads like the opinion of a random person on the Internet.  Would it be possible to [back up](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/17163) the claims with reliable sources please?  We should be aiming for high-quality, reliable answers.